# Problem with configuration of Dependency Injection in net framework 4.6.1 parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, config, simple-injector

I am creating new WCF service, on base of some old code. I think that I have done everything the same but during creating class using DI I get error:

### No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Below is my new code that is done on basics of working one:

```
public SChangeClaimHandlerStatusDTO ChangeClaimHandler(SChangeClaimHandlerMessageDTO message)
{
    (...)
    var status =
        ServiceProvider<Test.BusinessLayer.BusinessLogic.Order.S.SIntegrationService>
            .Service.ChangeClaimHandler(message);
    //line above is causing error
    (...)
    return status;
}
```

And below is called class:

```
public class SIntegrationService : ServiceBase 
{
    private const int SImageExpirationTimeInMinutes = 60;

    public SIntegrationService(
        IDocumentService documentService,
        IAttachmentService attachmentService,
        IUserService userService,
        ITextEncryptor textEncryptor, (...) )
    {
        RegisterService<IDocumentService>(documentService);
        RegisterService<IAttachmentService>(attachmentService);
        RegisterService<IUserService>(userService);
        RegisterService<ITextEncryptor>(textEncryptor);
        (...)
    }
}
```

```
public class ServiceBase : IBusinessService
{
    public ServiceBase();
    public ServiceBase(Dictionary<Type, object> dependencies);
    protected IAppContext ApplicationContext { get; }
    protected void RegisterService<T>(T dependency) where T : class;
}
```

And ServiceProvider class looking like this:

```
public class ServiceProvider<T> where T : class
{
    public ServiceProvider();

    public static T Service { get; }
}
```

class SIntegrationService has only one constructor (no parameterless constructor).
Both programs have in references SimpleInjector.

I`m rather new to DI, so maybe I am missing something obvious, maybe i should put something into config file to let know that there will be DI included?
I know that that should work in this way because I am staring on a code  in other project that is workink fine.

In other project config I also have this line:

```
<Services
  AutoWire="false"
  IocContainer="V.Common.Ioc.SimpleInjector.SimpleInjectorContainerAdapter, V.Common.Ioc.SimpleInjector"/>
```

maybe thats the solution?

Below is error details:

> System.MissingMethodException   HResult=0x80131513
> Message=No parameterless constructor defined for this object.
> Source    "mscorlib"  string
> StackTrace    "   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType >type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, >RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)\r\n
> at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
> skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)\r\n   at
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly,
> Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark&
> stackMark)\r\n   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean
> nonPublic)\r\n   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)\r\n
> at V.Common.Services.ServiceProvider`1.get_Service()\r\n   at
> BusinessServices.SIntegration.SIntegrationService.ChangeClaimHandler(SChangeClaimHandlerMessageDTO
> message) in D:\TFS1\Branches\Release 1.2.1
> Env01\ZV\BusinessServices.SIntegration\SOrderService.svc.cs:line
> 31\r\n   at SyncInvokeChangeClaimHandler(Object , Object[] , Object[]
> )\r\n   at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
> instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)\r\n   at
> System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
> rpc)" string

Comment: It`s in the ServiceBase class  above in my post.

Comment: Please post the complexe exception information including exception message, type, and stack trace of the exception and all its inner exceptions.

Comment: I added exception details to the post. Inner exceptions are null.

Comment: Following the [WCF integration guide](https://simpleinjector.org/wcf) should resolve your issues.

Comment: Now you followed the integration guide, did that answer your question, or are there any problems left? If so, please update your question (or ask a new one). Otherwise, please close this question.

Comment: Thanks for help but in my case following WCF Integration guide was not the solution. I have found that there was Initialize manager which creates needed instances. I added  into Global.asax lines:  "protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializerManager.DefaultInstance.RunOnce();
        }". And this solved my issues.